# How to make a menu that will change the language of my site

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web development and I want my site to have a drop-down menu that will change the language of my site.I want a solution that will not require me to create a whole new html of the new site. I also want a way to make an input field that will ask users to add a number and then it will automatically add a word after the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this maybe of some use to you - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the second part of the sentence is but a somewhat easy way of doing this is server-side scripting. For example, if you are using PHP, I would recommend you echo the a variable instead of actually typing the contents in the place it belongs. Instead, store the content in a database and then load the content from a database depending on what language is selected (store this a session variable), store it in the variable and when the variable is echoed, bam.

Answer (score 0):

Create in PHP by using $_GET[l];

```
 <?php
   if($_GET[l]=='en')
   {
          echo 'Welcome';
   }
   else if($_GET[l]=='sk')
   {
          echo 'Vítajte';
   }
   else if($_GET[l]=='de')
   {
          echo 'Wilkommen';
   }
   else
   {
          echo ''; //Here set your default language. For example if is not set- automatically to english
   }
 ?>
```

Menu:

```
 <?php
   if(isset($_GET[topic])) 
        {
              //This is code, if you use another $_GET[...]
              //Without this, page will crash ,while it shows another thing
         echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI].'&l=en">English</a>';
         echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI].'&l=sk">Slovensky</a>';
         echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI].'&l=de">Deutsch</a>';
              //?l=lang changes to &l=lang
        }
    else
        {
              //Link with normal ?l=lang, cause page does not use another $_GET[...]
          echo '<a href="?l=en">English</a>';
          echo '<a href="?l=sk">Slovensky</a>';
          echo '<a href="?l=de">Deutsch</a>';    
        }
 ?>
```